# How do i bind data to a child View Model?

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, zk

I have a page with two different View Models:

```
<?page title="My page" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.mycompany.FirstViewModel')">
<!-- A lot of unimportant stuff -->
<tabbox>
    <tabs>
        <tab label="Tab1" ></tab>
                    <!-- Other unimportant tabs -->
    </tabs>
    <tabpanels>
        <tabpanel>
        <include src="inc/other.zul" p="@ref(vm.selected)" pid="@ref(vm.selected.id)" ></include>
        </tabpanel>
    </tabpanels>
</tabbox>
</div>
```

And the include is:

```
<window>
    <label id="sid" value="@load(pid)" />
    <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
      viewModel="@id('vms') @init('com.mycompany.SecondViewModel')">
        <listbox model="@id('vars') @load(p.someList)"
            selectedItem="@bind(vms.selected)"
            emptyMessage="No data in list">
                    <!-- Template and stuff -->
        </listbox>
        <label id="sid1" value="@load(pid)" />
    </div>
</window>
```

The problem is that once I define the second viewModel, all the external references are inaccessible: I have a value for the first label, but I have no values for the listbox or the second label. Is there a way to do that? I tried with no success to do this:

```
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
viewModel="@id('vms') @init('com.mycompany.SecondViewModel')" list="@ref(p.someList)">
<listbox model="@id('vars') @load(list)"
    selectedItem="@bind(vms.selected)"
    emptyMessage="No data in list">
```

I could merge the second View Model in the first one, but that wouldn't be very convenient! I am also open to other solutions which allow me to have a modular approach.

My version of ZK is 6.0.1

Comment: Looking at http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Include#Pass_Values_to_the_Included_Page_2 passing of parameters is quite static and puts things into requestScope simply for the rendering phase of the outer page. When the user clicks on the tab panel later those parameter used in the original render are not re-evaluated. Bind the inner item to empty viewmodel. Put a global command on the tabbox select which the inner and outer view models can listen to and pass the selected date to the inner viewmodel via the desktopScope perhaps?

Comment: This refers to MVC, I use MVVM. Also, I am able to access the parameter from inside the include, it is the child view model that cannot access it anymore.

Comment: what an include does is independent of mvc, mvp or mvvm. the point is that things are not re-evaluated when the event is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is (was) actually a [bug](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1165) in ZK, which has been fixed for a future version.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are unable to access the external components is your composer i.e BindComposer you have same composer for the Main zul as well as for the Included zul. You need to access the Included Listbox from external ZUL.
So remove the Composer of Include ZUL, give an ID to window you have two Space Owners access the inner Listbox

```
<?page title="My page" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.mycompany.FirstViewModel')">
<!-- A lot of unimportant stuff -->
<tabbox>
    <tabs>
        <tab label="Tab1" ></tab>
                    <!-- Other unimportant tabs -->
    </tabs>
    <tabpanels>
        <tabpanel>
        <include id="include" src="inc/other.zul" p="@ref(vm.selected)" pid="@ref(vm.selected.id)" ></include>
        </tabpanel>
    </tabpanels>
</tabbox>
</div>


<window id="win">
    <label id="sid" value="@load(pid)" />
    <div 
      viewModel="@id('vms') @init('com.mycompany.SecondViewModel')">
        <listbox id="listbox2" model="@id('vars') @load(p.someList)"
            selectedItem="@bind(vms.selected)"
            emptyMessage="No data in list">
                    <!-- Template and stuff -->
        </listbox>
        <label id="sid1" value="@load(pid)" />
    </div>
</window>
```

Now while accessing in your BindComposer declare variable as public :

```
Listbox include$win$listbox2;
```

in your doAfterCompose() add this line

```
Sysout("You can access your inner Listbox and it is:"+include$win$listbox2);
```

Now you see you will not get your Listbox NULL!!

Link  : [http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/UI_Composing/ID_Space](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ID_Space)

Comment: I'm not sure I get that, if I remove the Composer from the included files `vms` is now defined to null, so whenever I click on an item in the list I get an exception. So basically I don't have the second ViewModel anymore...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you removed the `apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"` and added `id="win"`; I tried that, and vms does not contain a ViewModel... Also I do not have a doAfterCompose(), this is MVVM, not MVC...